# How to stop showing "online toast message" of mine to other gbwhatsapp users

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, privacy

This is very annoying that gbwhatsapp users are able to get toast notification when I come online from official `WhatsApp` App account(I am not using gbWhatsApp)

I am talking about getting instant notification/toast message of online in gbWhatsapp NOT showing "online" inside my window/profile. Also I am not asking about lastseen.

How can I stop this notification to them by using official WhatsApp app ?

Can someone comment if I can achieve this by using gbWhatsApp ?

Comment: By "*official whatsapp account*", did you mean "the official WhatsApp **app**", or are "you also using GBWhatsApp with the official WhatsApp account (whatever it means)"?

Comment: Hi, I've edited my old answer. You may check that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Not if you use the official WhatsApp app.
You can if you use modded WhatsApp (like GBwhatsapp, Aerowhatsapp, etc.) and you can freeze your last seen for everybody.

I personally don't recommend using modded apps since there could be a huge privacy threat.

---

**Edit:**

Since the last time I answered this question, WhatsApp has introduced a new feature of hiding even the online status.

[image]

Comment: Hi, lastseen is not my problem that I can hide with official WApp. But the notification other people is getting is my issue. I always use official WApp.

Comment: @r15 looks like this is an added feature of GBWhatsApp. If you're using the official WhatsApp app, then there's nothing you can do to prevent that since the official WhatsApp app doesn't support this feature in the first place.

Comment: @r15 I don't think you know that even if your last seen is turned off for everybody, WhatsApp shows you online when you come online. So there's nothing you can do about it with the official WhatsApp app (I strongly don't recommend using modded apps as I stated above)